# "Blend from shape" What does this do? how can I use it?

Tags: modeling, shape-keys

I can't find info in the manual or google. I want to learn about this option and what it does to shape keys? How can I use it?

https://docs.blender.org/manual/uk/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/vertex/blend_shape.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One very common use is to repair a shape key from a mistake, while leaving the desired deformations intact: if you like your shape key but you see some moving vertices that should stay still, you can select them, choose blend from shape, pointing at the basis shape, unchecking the "add" option (so to replace the moving vertices informations with the basis static locations).

Comment: What about the value of the shape key that needs to be kinda like "edited"? Should I set it to 0 while doing the steps you mentioned?

Comment: No, it should be set to 1, for total influence (go exactly in the basis locations). A value less than 1 will attenuate the effect of the shape key on those vertices. A value of 0 just does nothing.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like it's a way to copy the location of the selected vertices from another shapekey.

For example let say that it's your basis shapekey:

[image]

And this is your shapekey #1, called *Key 1* by default:

[image]

If you want one vertex to go back to the location it has in the basis shapekey, select this vertex, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> > *Blend from Shape*:

[image]

then in the *Operator* box select the shapekey from which you want to copy the vertex location, tweak the *Blend* value:

[image]

Now your *Key 1* will look like that, the vertex gets the position it has in the basis shapekey:

[image]